# Does Outlook import contacts not support non-ASCII characters?

Tags: csv, outlook, non-ascii-characters

How to import csv format contacts file with non-ASCII characters?

When importing an UTF-8 format contacts.csv file into Outlook, Outlook couldn't recognize non-ASCII characters, as following:

[image]

But if manually entering the non-ASCII characters, it's fine:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: At what point are you telling Outlook the character encoding of your file?

Comment: @TomBlodget The csv file is a locally saved UTF-8 file which the user can select for importing into Outlook. There is no step to tell Outlook the character encoding type. Here is the steps link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-contacts-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-outlook-f6483469-0684-4c30-82c5-c881930f5451

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other program that handles text files, if Outlook isn't asking which encoding you are using then it must be telling you which single encoding you must use (probably through documentation.) Unfortunately, the page you linked is missing this essential information. Hopefully, it would be an encoding for a character set that supports all the characters in your file.

When you find out, you can convert with PowerShell:

```
Get-Content -Encoding UTF-8 contactsUTF8.csv | Out-File -Encoding Whatever contactsForImport.csv
```

It could be that a program uses the old way of adapting to use the user's default encoding. In that case:

```
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 contactsUTF8.csv | Out-File -Encoding Default contactsForImport.csv
```

In all cases, though there could be silent data loss if the target character set doesn't support all of the characters in the text file.

You might also try importing via OWA, if you have that available.